# SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader:

Tags: metadata-api

I'm integerating two salesforce instences via metadata api with access token, with reference to following github project.
https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

So i updated the createService() code as follows to retrieve the acess token as the session ID. But ended up getting mentioned error. Can someone suggest me a workaround for this?

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort(); service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();

//service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId(); 
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = clientAccessToken;

//I tried setting following as the endpoint_x. But was getting separate error
//service.endpoint_x = 'https://login.salesforce.com';
```

Thanks

Comment: It's complaining about session id, try debugging the passed value.

Comment: I think you are passing Access Token into Session Id, they both are different. for more information go through http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/security-token-vs-session-id-vs-access-token